# How to create Mapbox Tileset from PDF

Tags: vector, convert, tiles, mapbox, indoor

I've the floor plan for a building in PDF. I'm trying to upload this into Mapbox as a tileset but I'm having a lot of confusion regarding the conversion.

How should I approach this?

P.S. since I'm new to GIS, please provide detailed explanations

Answer (score 3):

Does the PDF have building footprints or any other geographic information? Do you have access to ArcMap? If so, you could export the PDF to a GeoTIFF (public domain metadata standard or type of tagged image file format that allows georeferencing information to be embedded within a TIFF). After that initial conversion is complete Mapbox would then be able to ingest the GeoTIFF. If you do not have access to ArcMap you will need to find another way to convert the PDF to a GeoTIFF (I did some research and did not find another alternative).

Moving forward, to upload a new Tileset into Studio it should be in one of the following formats: "MBTiles, KML, GPX, GeoJSON, Shapefile (zipped), or CSV to convert it into vector tiles or upload a GeoTIFF to convert it into raster tiles". This information can be found in the Home section of studio when you click on "Tilesets".

Here is a PDF to TIFF workflow for ArcMap 10.3: 
http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/conversion-toolbox/pdf-to-tiff.htm

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

just use QGIS with QMetaTiles to create an mbtiles of your Tiff

I would convert your GeoPDF to Tiff first with GDAL_Translate

gdal_translate -of "GTiff" -co "COMPRESS=LZW" -r cubic "path\source.pdf" "path\output.tif

Another option if you have Global Mapper it's great reading GeoPDF and can write to TMS/XYZ and mbtiles formats

Comment: the question seems to mention a regular PDF file, not a georeferenced one

Comment: QGIS has a GeoReferencer you can georeference the image first adding ground control points